# Update stats step failed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have scheduled weekly maintenance, which is first run rebuild or reorg depends on fragmentation level. Next step will update stats for individual databases.

Update stats is failing with unknown reason also getting below error we didn't find anything to troubleshoot. When running same statement ns query window its completed successfully

> The step failed (no other specific reasons for failure)

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: You haven't included any of the SQL you're running either. How can we debug something we can't see?